# How can I do responsive column width in Ag Grid for React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid-react

I use react Ag Grid library and ı work 1920*1080 screensize. So I need use responsive column width for another screensize.

````
               { headerName: "Sıra", field: "", width: 30, minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 300, suppressSizeToFit: false },
               { headerName: "Subscriber No", field: "", width: 130, minWidth: 10, maxWidth: 450, suppressSizeToFit: false },
...
] ```

I tried percantage instead of "30" but it doesn't work. How can I set percentage value for responsive design in Ag Grid?
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend calling `gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();` in your onGridReady callback.  This will adjust the size of all columns to exactly fill in the available width of the grid.  When you set the `width` property of the column definition to 30, it is in pixels, not percent.